# Unable to echo PHP variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP variable which contains a `JSON` object in string format.

```
<?php
$url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
$phpObj = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var obj = "<?php echo $phpObj; ?>";
</script>
```

When I try to echo a PHP variable in `javascript`, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

I've tried using `json_encode`, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: When you render the page, can you "view source" and paste it here?

Comment: First off ditch the quotes `var obj = <?php echo $phpObj; ?>`; it's a string in PHP but in JS you want `var obj = {foo:bar};` not  `var obj = "{foo:bar}";`

Comment: May we see some sample data?  We need to know exactly how the input data may vary.

Comment: response of request can return json data or array by file_get_contents, try var obj = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($phpObj) ?>"); hope help you

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the quotes (`"`s) and `json_encode` as it is already a **JSON** object. Try

```
var obj = <?php echo $phpObj; ?>;
```

When I ma fetching the data and try -

```
<?php
$phpObj = file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json");
?>

<script>
var obj = <?php echo $phpObj; ?>;
console.log(obj);
</script>
```

I am getting -

```
{as: "AS45194 Syscon Infoway Pvt. Ltd.", city: "Thane", country: "India", countryCode: "IN", isp: "Syscon Infoway Pvt.", …}
```

in the console.

Comment: I removed the quotes and tried. But when I view source it gives me: var obj = <br /> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: Can you add the content you are getting in `$phpObj`?

Comment: @Teemu works with out the quotes too. Also if the quotes required the it needs to be escaped in this case.

Comment: @Sougata Double quotes are used within JSON, so you should wrap it in single quotes shouldn't you?

Comment: *http://ip-api.com/json* contains JSON string. Maybe OP is getting some different content. So we need to confirm that first.

Comment: My Webroot says that link is "High Risk".  "Detected Malicious Site"

Comment: @mickmackusa see the source after visiting that url. Its simple JSON.

Comment: ...I'll wait for the OP to update the question with input data.

Comment: A lot of PHP errors start with `<br />`  [For example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df5cfa546dc36e44a091111969ac9c24f9dfa767)  My guess is you have some kind of notice or warning generating output in your code.

Comment: $phpObj contains data similar to : {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}. Unable to post actual values as it contains location sensitive information.

Comment: Then I guess we cannot solve because your question is Unclear / Cannot be Reproduced.

Comment: Working perfectly for me without the quotes. Updating with full code.

Comment: So can we safely assume that the OP has something else that is fouling up the process?

Answer (score 0):

Passing simple arrays or arrays of objects between PHP and JavaScript can be done through `json_encode` and `json_decode` respectively. For instance, in your case, I can do the following

```
<?php
  $url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
  $phpObj = file_get_contents($url);
?>
 <script>
  var obj = <?php echo $phpObj; ?>;
 </script>
```

Since the data fetched is JSON.

However, this fully depends on your application. If `$phpObj = file_get_contents($url);` returns json then I will simply do the following

```
<script>
  var obj = <?php echo $phpObj; ?>;
 </script>
```

If it's an object that is returned(`$phpObj`), then I will, first of all, convert the object to an array then parse it into JSON format then echo it to JavaScript as shown below

```
<script>
  var obj = <?php echo json_encode((array)$phpObj); ?>;
 </script>
```

If it's an array that is returned, then I will parse the variable to JSON format then echo it to JavaScript as shown below

```
<script>
  var obj = <?php echo json_encode($phpObj); ?>;
 </script>
```

For the case of `json_decode`, if for instance, you want to use the value returned by `file_get_contents($url);` and assuming this returns JSON, you can convert the JSON to a PHP array or a PHP object as shown below,

```
$data_obj = json_decode($phpObj); //Return object not array
$data_arr = json_decode($phpObj,true); //Return array not object
```